# Is it possible to create a DbContext Interface or abstract class and use it to inject different DbContext Objects?

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework

I have a software product which database was created on SQLServer and the table and column names were defined by the dev team, the model was then imported to Visual Studio using Database First approach , now we are developing the same type of solution for other company that uses ORACLE and request a naming convention for the Tables and Columns so in order to not change the existing code and use Code-First Approach, I created a DbContext with the correct naming conventions using the [Column] attribute for all the classes properties, but now I'm trying to create an interface so we can Inject different DbContext and in the future we have a more flexible solution.

I'm new to .Net but my approach is to make an Abstract Class for the DbContext, and an interface for every class that represents a table so in the implementation of each of those classes i can change the table and columns names if necessary. My question is, it's possible? and is a good approach?

Comment: Im not sure if this is possible or not, but it seems your problem could more simply be solved with a resources file that defines the underlying table and column names as compile-time constants. Just switch out the resource file at compile time for different back ends.

Comment: one additional problem that i have is the use of Guid, for SQL-Server the mapping is direct, but for Oracle we have been using string and modifying the code accordingly, which is other thing i want to stop doing, thanks.

Comment: Take a look at EF7, there are several providers and you may be able to create another one https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2015/11/18/entity-framework-7-rc1-available/

Comment: @NicolasRestrepo I'm curious as to how the experiment went.  Seems like it was a good plan

Answer (score 15, accepted):

No, there isn't. But you can always build one like this:

```
interface IDbContext : IDisposable
{
    DbSet<TEntity> Set<TEntity>() where TEntity : class;

    Task<int> SaveChangesAsync();
}

public class MyDbContext : DbContext, IDbContext
{
    public MyDbContext()
        : base("myConnectionString")
    { }

    //implementation
}
```

And inject `IDbContext` when needed.

Comment: the controllers that need the context object use it in LINQ statements , like this: from p in context.ExecutionLog where p.ProcessCode == proccessCode, so my IDbContext needs to define an ExecutionLog DbSet and i need an IExecutionLog interface so i can reference the generic properties of that class in the LINQ statements, how could i implement that with your approach. Thanks

Comment: @NicolasRestrepo Use `context.Set<ExecutionLog>` to get the table data.

Comment: Yes I Realized this was the way to do it yesterday, it's working and i only needed to refactor some code, the only problem i found was that the SQLServer db was created using Guid for the keys, and when the migration to Oracle occurred they used a varchar because there is no data type in Oracle that maps directly to Guid , and then change the code... So i'm now evaluating a way to use the same data types in both dbs

Answer (score 1):

I achieved it like this.

Created a custom interface with the IQueryable<> properties that I need.

```
public interface IDataContext
{
    public IQueryable<Entity> EntityData { get; }
}
```

Created an Entity Framework context class with explicit interface implementation.

```
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

public class Context : DbContext, IDataContext
{
    public DbSet<Entity> Entities { get; set; }

    IQueryable<Entity> IDataContext.EntityData => Entities;
}
```

Made a DI definition for the context.

```
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;

public static void AddContext(this IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddScoped<IDataContext, Context>();
}
```

Injected it into class that uses context.

```
private readonly IDataContext _context;

public UsingClass(IDataContext context)
{
    _context = context;
}

// Sample method that shows usage. Not async, but you get the idea.
private Entity[] GetQueryable()
{
    return _context.EntityData.ToArray();
}
```

I hope dependency injection stuff does not make it confusing, but providing explicit interface implementation did the trick for me. This allows me to completely mock DbContext.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a generic class with several type parameter constraints and, for example, a public property of the constrained type to inject your `DbContext`:

```
class Stuff<T> where T : DbContext, IMyContext
{
    public T Context { get; set; }
    // other members
}
```

This makes you able to use `DbContext` as well as `IMyContext` functionality for variables of type `T`.

Comment: not really, your class has to be both DbContext *and* IMyContext

Comment: @Sten-Petrov, this is only a way to inject different db-contexts which implement certain model signature.

Answer (score 0):

Old question, different context (no pun intended), but it appears that at least for unit testing purposes it has been possible for a while to inject a database context with its interface.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/testing-and-debugging/mocking-entity-framework-when-unit-testing-aspnet-web-api-2#add-dependency-injection