# Controller DbContext Dependency Injection with EF

Tags: rest, dependency-injection, interface, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-webapi

Have a web api project.
In the controller I would like to use dependeny injection like this:

```
[ApiController]
public class BookingsController : ControllerBase
{
    private readonly InterfaceDbContext _context;

    public BookingsController(InterfaceDbContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }

    // GET: api/<BookingsController>
    [HttpGet]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Get()
    {
        var bookings = await _context.Booking.ToListAsync();
        return Ok(bookings);
    }
```

But if I use Dependency Injection I can't access Booking as the InterfaceDbContext does not contain that particular DbSet/Bookings.

The DbSet/Bookings I want to get is in a context called TvattDbContext that implements the InterfaceDbContext(InterfaceDbContext is basically empty).

Would like to understand the value of using InterfaceDbContext in the BookingsController constructor  as it doesn't feel like there is a difference if I use the TvattDbContext directly instead?  If I have the DbSet/Booking in the interface then why not just use the TvattDbContext in the controller constructor instead and skip the interface?

Comment: What prevents you from using  BookingsController(TvattDbContext context)?

Comment: Nothing at all, just thought it would be better to use an interface and DI, isn't it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it possible to create a DbContext Interface or abstract class and use it to inject different DbContext Objects?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37817522/is-it-possible-to-create-a-dbcontext-interface-or-abstract-class-and-use-it-to-i)

Comment: @JoBo you don't need to create interface for DI. You can use the class as well, as the most developers do.  In the most cases, developers use interfaces only because they need unit testing.

Comment: I'm not sure where the API project fits into my architecture, it currently has references to both Core and Infrastructure but it seems like it shouldn't have references to Infrastructure(my dbContext) as it is an outer layer of the clean architecture onion right? 
Hence I thought I would use DI to change the dependency. 

Maybe the api projcet with it's controller is outside the infrastructre onion layer? Or are they on the same level.

Comment: The API project should add the data layer reference, then it can query the database and return the relate data to the client side. I suggest you could learn the [Repository Pattern](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/architecture/microservices/microservice-ddd-cqrs-patterns/infrastructure-persistence-layer-implementation-entity-framework-core)(#The Repository and Unit of Work Patterns) first. Then, if use an easier way to query data, you could directly inject the TvattDbContext, but it will expose all the `DbSet<T>`, if using the Repository (interface), you can define the expose methods.